# What is % in Unix Shell

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I am currently looking at a shell script which makes use of '%' sign.

```
%.gtf.checked: %.gtf
    irap_check_gtf $(gtf_file_abspath) && touch $@
```

I am not being able to understand the use of '%', any ideas?
I tried searching already but all the uses i found for the '%' sign don't seem to match the presented situation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a *"shell"* command, but part of a ***makefile***.  In make, the `"%"` acts as a type of wildcard (more correctly, ["pattern matching"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules)).

Further reading: [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, It's used to pass a parameter from the script command...

For example,  if you command was `scriptfile filename` then in the script the % would be replaced with `filename` when the script was executed.